# Python understanding the scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I've a `python scheduler` code to print `Hello` and `World!`.

```
import sched
import time

def x():
    print "Hello"

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(10, 1, x, ())
s.run()
print "World!"
```

This waits for `10 seconds` and outputs:

```
Hello
World!
```

I think a scheduler's job is to schedule a task without interrupting the current process. But here it's putting the whole program to sleep and behaves just like the below code:

```
import time

def x():
    print "Hello"

time.sleep(10)
x()
print "World!"
```

I guess the scheduler makes the program to sleep due to the `time.sleep` parameter in `sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)`.
Is there anyway we can make it work just like a real-time scheduler without blocking the main process without using any `multithreading` or `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html):

> In multi-threaded environments, the `scheduler` class has limitations with respect to thread-safety, inability to insert a new task before the one currently pending in a running scheduler, and holding up the main thread until the event queue is empty. Instead, the preferred approach is to use the `threading.Timer` class instead.

```
from threading import Timer

def x():
    print "Hello"

Timer(10, x, ()).start()
print "World!"
```

> without blocking the main process without using any `multithreading` or `multiprocessing`

A single thread can't be doing two things at the same time, so... `threading` is the absolute minimum you need to use in order not to block.

Comment: Thanks. I never thought we can have `scheduler` without the `sched` library or using `cron job`.

Comment: Well, `cron` is still the only thing that will work if you want to schedule something outside of the time your process is executing. The above solution, as well as any other non-cron solution, will by necessity have your process executing while it is waiting to trigger your job.

Comment: For now I'll settle with the `threading.Timer`. If needed, I'll shift to `cron`. `sched` is not of any use to me. :P

Comment: Can you help me with how to cancel the `Timer` in between or reset it?

Comment: Again, [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects): "Timers are started, as with threads, by calling their `start()` method. The timer can be stopped (before its action has begun) by calling the `cancel()` method."

Comment: I tried but got this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cancel'` and at the end it print `Hello`. So i guess, Timer didn't stop after the `Error`.

Comment: `t = Timer(10, x, ()); t.start(); t.cancel()` works; I think you may have done `t = Timer(10, x, ()).start()`, which is `None`, and then tried to cancel that.

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. Is there any way I can reset it? For now I'm trying `t.cancel(); t.start()`. But getting an error: `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once.`

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler's job is to not only execute the subsequent tasks after every particular time period. its job is also to lock the object until it completes its task.

```
from threading import Timer

def xy():
    print("End")

Timer(4, xy, ()).start()
print ("Start")
```

Initially, **Start** will be printed, then  4 sec later **End** will be printed.

What if we have an endless loop

```
from threading import Timer

def xy():
    print("End")

Timer(4, xy, ()).start()
print("Start")
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
```

It will be running continuously. Hence, It is proved that it will hold the thread until the prev one completes its task.